# CIPSEND Shows 404 error using aeduino + esp8266+01

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, wifi

I am trying  to save data in the data base with the get method. my url works fine when used with browser but when tried with esp shows page not found expection. 
Arduino Code

````
SoftwareSerial ESP8266(10, 11); // Rx,  Tx

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  ESP8266.begin(9600); 

  ESP8266.println("AT+RST");
  delay(1000);
  ESP8266.print("AT+CWQAP\r\n");
  delay(2000);
  unsigned char check_connection=0;
  unsigned char times_check=0;
  Serial.println("Connecting to Wifi");

  while(check_connection==0)
  {
    Serial.print(".");
  ESP8266.print("AT+CWJAP=\"********\",\"*******\"\r\n");
  ESP8266.setTimeout(5000);
 if(ESP8266.find("WIFI CONNECTED\r\n")==1)
 {
 Serial.println("WIFI CONNECTED");
 break;
 }
 times_check++;
 if(times_check>3) 
 {
  times_check=0;
   Serial.println("Trying to Reconnect..");
  }
  }
  delay(5000);
}

void loop() {

  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
   String cmd = "AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"";
  cmd += "homeautomationinternal.xyz"; // api.thingspeak.com
  cmd += "\",80";
  ESP8266.println(cmd);
  if(ESP8266.find("Error")){
    Serial.println("AT+CIPSTART error");
    return;
  }
  String getStr = "GET /auto/addlightvalueuseruno?userid=aravind";
  //getStr += String(temp_f);
  getStr +="&";
  getStr +="value=1";
  //getStr += String(humidity);
  getStr +=" HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: homeautomationinternal.xyz";
  getStr += "\r\n\r\n";
  // send data length
  cmd = "AT+CIPSEND=";
  cmd += String(getStr.length());
  ESP8266.println(cmd);
  ESP8266.setTimeout(2000);
  if(ESP8266.find(">")){
    ESP8266.print(getStr);
   Serial.println(cmd);
  }
  else{
    ESP8266.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");
    // alert user
    Serial.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");
  }
   Serial.println(getStr);
  delay(5000);

}```

and the serial monitor data is 

```AT+CIPSTART="TCP","www.homeautomationinternal.xyz",80

CONNECT

OK
 AT+CIPSEND=98


OK
> 
busy s...

Recv 98 bytes

SEND OK

+IPD,1245:<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>404 - File or directory not found.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>404 - File or directory not found.</h2>
  <h3>The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
CLOSED
````

my website runs on iis server..

please help me with the arduino code and error which I am getting in the serial.monitor and how to resolve it.

Comment: As I am send data from Arduino to my website using get method I thought there may be any error with the hosting technicque @jsotola

Comment: Just ignore the iis please help me with the error and how to resolve it

Comment: how should we help you? the url is not valid for the server. how should we know what is a valid url on your server?

Comment: please let me know what all the details you require iwill provide you@Juraj

Comment: why this url? does it work from browser?

Comment: yes it works for browser . this url www.homeautomationinternal.xyz/auto/addlightvalueuseruno?userid=aravind&value=1 returns a json value 1

Comment: this is a home automation project which activates relay.. the arduino sends data to server using get method and we can see the data in website@Juraj

Comment: in code I don't see www in hostname

Comment: do we need to provide the www in host name...didnt work even after providing www in host name.. i am getting an error that webpage is not found i.e 404 error.

Comment: did you add the www in Host header too? 'www' is the name of the server. you can't leave it out

Comment: yaa i have added didnt work

Comment: You server is set up to redirect everything to `https://www.homeautomationinternal.xyz` which the ESP-01 doesn't like. You'd be much better off programming the ESP-01 directly with your website interaction code so that then it can handle the connections properly.

Comment: can you please help me with it how to do that@Majenko

Comment: and how did you came to know that its redirecting to home page

Comment: try `AT+CIPSTART=\"SSL\",` with `cmd += "\",443";`